# Access error 3043 (network access interrupted) when using module code to import

Tags: vba, ms-access, module

I'm new to Access as well as VB so please bear with me.

I've found and modified a small snip of code to connect to a password protected access db on the network in an attempt to import the table defs and data into a separate database (effectively a copy).

The problem I'm running into is when I execute the code I get a 3043 error and the tables are not imported. This does not happen when I use the GUI import tool through access.

does anyone know why I only receive this error when using the code (executed via macro), and how I might diagnose the issue for myself in the future?

Or perhaps a better way to automate the importing of data? This was the first method that popped in my head after a bit of digging, so if there is a better way to approach this I'm all for learning.

Code snipit for reference (if I'm using bad practices or doing something wrong please point it out):

```
Public Function ImportAllTbls(sExtDbPath As String, sExtDbName As String, sExtDbPass As String)
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim acc As Access.Application
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim fullDbPath As String

    fullDbPath = sExtDbPath & "\" & sExtDbName

    Set acc = New Access.Application
    acc.Visible = True
    acc.OpenCurrentDatabase fullDbPath, False, sExtDbPass
    Set db = acc.CurrentDb()

    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs 'Loop through all the table in the external database
        If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then 'Exclude System Tables
            On Error GoTo Error_Handler
            acc.DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", fullDbPath + ";pwd=" + sExtDbPass, acTable, tdf.Name, tdf.Name, False, False
        End If
    Next tdf
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing

Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "MS Access has generated the following error" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & _
    Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Error Source: ImportAllTbls" & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & _
    Err.Description, vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: The code you have posted is not VB.NET.  If that's the actual code you're using then you must not be using VB.NET, but rather VB6 or VBA.  In that case, please fix the tags assigned to this question.  If you are using VB.NET and what you posted is not the actual code you're using, please post the actual code you're using.

Comment: The tag I entered was just VB, I don't know how it got changed to VB.NET... I think it is VBA, I'll have to look into it a bit more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure the acc is needed, you might try just:

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", fullDbPath + ";pwd=" + sExtDbPass, acTable, tdf.Name, tdf.Name, False, False
        End If

This syntax is very suspect:  + ";pwd=" + sExtDbPass

I would suggest you manually type in the path and password; rather than call it - - just as a sanity check to get at least it working..... and then do more research on the correct syntax of your Where statement regarding the PW.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the syntax issue. I don't know what I was doing... but now the application prompts me for the password to copy each table. though I would rather not enter it at all, I could live with doing so once. do you know how to set it up so I don't have to enter the password for each table?

Comment: As a side note, no the acc is not needed otherwise you will be doing the action on the remote db as opposed to the local one. just for anyone who is looking at this later.

Comment: Marking as answer as the syntax error was causing the network connection error. thank you again for the help.